# Не работает ng-repeat AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Почему не работает вывод?

```js
var model = [{ title: "IT вебинар «Чем интересен Entity Framework 6?»", published: "11.02.2015 г", description: "Приглашаем начинающих и опытных .NET разработчиков, а также всех, кто интересуется новыми технологиями, принять участие в бесплатном вебинаре учебного центра CyberBionic Systematics о новых возможностях взаимодействия с базами данных, которые доступны в новой версии ADO.NET Entity Framework.", link: "http://itvdn.com/ru/news/article?id=vebinar-entity-framework6" }, 
{ title: "Итоги презентации Microsoft", published: "23.01.2015 г", description: "21 Января Microsoft провела первую презентацию в новом году. Публике были представлены очередные возможности Windows 10, а также другие потребительские продукты. В этой новости мы расскажем про самые интересные обновления и нововведения продуктов.", link: "http://itvdn.com/ru/news/article?id=presentation-of-microsoft" },
{ title: "JavaScript назван языком 2014 года", published: "15.01.2015 г.", description: "Портал TIOBE опубликовал итоговый рейтинг языков за 2014 год, и в категории «Язык года» победителем стал - JavaScript.", link: "http://itvdn.com/ru/news/article?id=javascript-language" },
{ title: "IT вебинары для начинающих программистов в январе", published: "13.01.2015 г.", description: "Приглашаем Вас на серию бесплатных вебинаров для начинающих программистов, которые состоятся 22 и 29 января.Вебинар Семантика HTML5, создаем змейку используя canvas расчитан на начинающих веб разработчиков, владеющих HTML и базовыми знаниями JavaScript.", link: "http://itvdn.com/ru/news/article?id=it-webinar-january-2015" },
{ title: "Microsoft планирует запустить новый браузер вместе с Windows 10", published: "06.01.2015 г.", description: "Компания Microsoft разрабатывает совершенно новый браузер, более известный под кодовым называнием “Spartan”. Он будет отличаться от Internet Explorer и войдет в новую операционную систему Windows 10. Основная задача браузера – уйти от негативного имиджа IE.", link: "http://itvdn.com/ru/news/article?id=new-browser" }];


/*Module*/
var newsApp = angular.module("newsApp",[]);

/*Controller*/

newsApp.controller("newsAppCtrl", function($scope){
  $scope.data = model;
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <col-md-12>
    <h1>ITVDN News</h1>
  </col-md-12>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 ng-repeat="data in data">
      <h2>{{data.title}}</h2>
      <span class="publ">{{data.published}}</span>
      <p class="desc">{{data.description}}</p>
      <span class="link">{{data.link}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас class не закрыт

```
<div class="col-md-12 ng-repeat="data in data">
```

Должно быть

```
<div class="col-md-12" ng-repeat="data in data">
```

Плюс для переменной я бы задал отличное имя

```
<div class="col-md-12" ng-repeat="element in data">
```